# List index out of range during array concatenation attempt

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, range

`enter code here`I tried searching but couldn't find the precise solution to this problem. I understand list index errors occur when python a specified index is impossible or out of range. For this problem, I've been scratching my head, because I believe it should be theoretically possible.

Essentially, I have three separate arrays, and I want to concatenate their corresponding elements, i.e. the first element of array1, the first element of array2, and the first element of array3

Then, I want to concatenate the second element of array1, the second element of array 2, and the second element of array3, etc and so forth.

Here's the code I have:

```
i = 0
for i in range (len(array1)):                     #all arrays are the same length

    string_conc = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]

    master_array.append(string_conc)

    i = i + 1
```

This returns this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    string_conc = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's strange, is that when I manually input the the values for the array elements, it works just fine - i.e.:

```
i = 0
for i in range (len(array1)):                     #all arrays are the same length

    string_conc = array1[0] + array2[0] + array3[0]

    master_array.append(string_conc)

    i = i + 1
```

When i is printed, it returns its proper value.

What am I missing here? It seems that the loop can't retrieve the value of i. When I also define i within the loop, it works - but this comes into logical problem of resetting the value of i to 0 every single time the loop is run.

Comment: Why is this tagged "out"? And why isn't it tagged "Python"? :P

Comment: Your error message does not match your code.

Comment: You don't need `i = 0` (because the `for` loop takes care of that), nor do you need `i = i + 1`.

Comment: Apologize about the tag, this is my first post on stackoverflow; error message doesn't match because I tried a last-minute tweak (converting it to an integer) and didn't catch the discrepancy when I copy and pasted it.

Comment: You say that "all arrays are the same length".  Maybe we should check that: right before the loop, add `print len(array1), len(array2), len(array3)`, and let us know the results.

Comment: Ahhh!!! I printed them out and the first array is one element longer. This is probably the problem. Thanks! I have now learned the pitfalls of assumptions.

Comment: Confirmed that different-size arrays were the problem. The script now works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This one function should suffice:

```
zip(array1, array2, array3)
```

This makes little sub-lists containing one element from each list. If you want them string-concatenated, you can use this:

```
[''.join(s) for s in zip(array1, array2, array3)]
```

Comment: Theoretically, incrementing the counter manually at the end of the loop should have no effect. What that means for the OP's real code is hard to say, as the error doesn't match the posted code.

Comment: @user2357112: You are correct; it was transference from other languages. I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
master_array = []    
for i in range (len(array1)-1):                    

    string_conc = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]

    master_array.append(string_conc)
```

Your problem was you were using `i` for two different tasks, which is did not work the way you wanted it to.

What you were trying to do was:

```
i = 0
for iterations in range(len(array1)-1): # note iterations not i                    

    string_conc = array1[i] + array2[i] + array3[i]

    master_array.append(string_conc)

    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Your recommended code will miss the last elements.  `range` doesn't include the upper bound, so `range(len(array1))` produces the right indices to access a sequence with `len(array1)` elements.